# Flutter - How to create a Search Bar using a text field widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, search, searchbar

I am creating a search bar on the new page. I don't want the search iconbutton onpressed search delegate method. I want a search field like below.

[image]

So I am using the Textfield widget. **If I enter some text in the text field, suggested results should be displayed.** How to achieve this?

The code I tried was:

```
SizedBox(
              height: 45,
              width: 360,
              child: TextField(
                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                  color: const Color(0xff020202),
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  letterSpacing: 0.5,
                ),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: const Color(0xfff1f1f1),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                    borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                  ),
                  hintText: "Search for Items",
                  hintStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                      color: const Color(0xffb2b2b2),
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      letterSpacing: 0.5,
                      decorationThickness: 6),
                  prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.search),
                  prefixIconColor: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 2):

Imagine we have a list of Strings we want to search between, in more complicated cases, we will search between our classes and custom objects but the following example should be descriptive:

1. Create a list of Strings

```dart
final List<String> myCoolStrings = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4', 'Some other item'];
```

2. Create our local search results list

```dart
final List<String> _results = []; // Empty at start
```

3. We will, at last, make our function which handles the search

```dart
void _handleSearch(String input){
  _results.clear();
  for (var str in myCoolStrings){
    if(str.toLowerCase().contains(input.toLowerCase())){
      setState(() {
        _results.add(str);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Use it like the following (Edited your code):

```dart
SizedBox(
              height: 45,
              width: 360,
              child: TextField(
                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                  color: const Color(0xff020202),
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  letterSpacing: 0.5,
                ),
                onChanged: _handleSearch,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: const Color(0xfff1f1f1),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                    borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                  ),
                  hintText: "Search for Items",
                  hintStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                      color: const Color(0xffb2b2b2),
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      letterSpacing: 0.5,
                      decorationThickness: 6),
                  prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.search),
                  prefixIconColor: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Some things I have to explain:
You can also use the function like `onChanged: (value) => _handleSearch(value),` But since our function is exactly what that property is asking for, we made it more beautiful.

And at the end, we will implement the changes. Let's say we have a ListView.builder:

```dart
// We will use ternary operators for a cleaner code
_results.isEmpty ? ListView.builder(itemCount: myCoolStrings.count) : ListView.builder(itemCount: _results.count),
```

A more detailed example:

```dart
class ListViewSearchExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListViewSearchExample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ListViewSearchExample> createState() => _ListViewSearchExampleState();
}

class _ListViewSearchExampleState extends State<ListViewSearchExample> {
  final List<String> myCoolStrings = [
    'Item 1',
    'Item 2',
    'Item 3',
    'Item 4',
    'Some other item'
  ];

  final List<String> _results = [];

  void _handleSearch(String input) {
    _results.clear();
    for (var str in myCoolStrings) {
      if (str.toLowerCase().contains(input.toLowerCase())) {
        setState(() {
          _results.add(str);
        });
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("ListView.builder")),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 45,
            width: 360,
            child: TextField(
              onChanged: _handleSearch,
              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                color: const Color(0xff020202),
                fontSize: 20,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                letterSpacing: 0.5,
              ),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                filled: true,
                fillColor: const Color(0xfff1f1f1),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                  borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                ),
                hintText: "Search for Items",
                hintStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                    color: const Color(0xffb2b2b2),
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    letterSpacing: 0.5,
                    decorationThickness: 6),
                prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.search),
                prefixIconColor: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: _results.isEmpty
                ? ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: myCoolStrings.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      final data = myCoolStrings[index];
                      return ListTile(
                          leading: const Icon(Icons.list),
                          trailing: const Text(
                            "GFG",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green, fontSize: 15),
                          ),
                          title: Text(data));
                    })
                : ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: _results.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      final data = _results[index];
                      return ListTile(
                          leading: const Icon(Icons.list),
                          trailing: const Text(
                            "GFG",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green, fontSize: 15),
                          ),
                          title: Text(data));
                    }),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Where should the last line of cleaner code be generated? If I use ListView Builder, I get errors.

Comment: @Divya Check this link out: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/lists/long-lists ... It's from the official documents of Flutter, you need a builder to build your widgets. I gave you a minimal example. You need itemCount, and itemBuilder. itemBuilder passes you two objects, one is context of that builder, the other one is index of your item. I have edited my answer to include a better example.